# Tips on creating a upstart script

Tags: upstart

I have a few questions that I'm looking for some pointers for.

1. Once I create my upstart .conf file, how exactly do I "install" it and activate it?
2. How do you go about debugging the script while developing it?  Example, I may be looping to form a list of files in the script, is it possible to output the result to console so I know its working?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've created your conf file, simply put it in `/etc/init/` for system jobs, or in `~/.init` for user job. For more info:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-configuration-file
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-log

By default the console output of your script is in `/var/log/upstart/file.log`.